# Static classes in C#, what's the pros/cons?

Tags: c#, class, methods, static

I am programming a small game for my school assignment, the game is a simple 2D game with monsters, items and bullets. Basically you run around and tries to collect all the item coins, the monsters tries to prevent you and you can shoot them down with the bullets that you collect. Very simple.

The question is, i have added the monsters, items, walls, player and bullets to a static class named LiveObjects, these objects can i then access from any place in the code. Is it a bad practice? Whats the alternative? (It's not multithreaded)

LiveObjects.cs

```
internal static class LiveObjects
{        
    public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>(); // List with all the items
    public static List<Monster> monsters = new List<Monster>(); // List with all present monsters
    public static List<Wall> walls = new List<Wall>(); // List with the walls
    public static List<Bullet> bullets = new List<Bullet>(); // List with the bullets
    public static Player player = new Player(0, 0); // The player object
}
```

I use a lot of different classes to manipulate the data inside the LiveObjects and then to avoid passing an entire List, i can just call it directly inside any method.

Comment: This is a fine solution Patrick as per the mostly positive feedback below, but i would wrap your public members with properties rather than exposing them directly. Using properties will give you some flexibility down the road as well as enable you to easily make use of thread synchronization for accessing your objects. A light tutorial on properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pros:

- Easy access
- Easy coding

Cons:

- No thread safety
- No encapsulation
- Reduced maintainability

Answer (score 1):

If your application is multithreaded you might need to think about the issues around multiple threads accessing and modifying static instances. Here's a good artical on threading:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of static classes is that it is the only place you can define extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't intend this as a serious answer but among the pro's, as you have discovered, is that it's very simple to get to your entities.

Among the con's is that some people hate static classes so much that they will not hire you because you've used them. http://thegrenade.blogspot.com/2009/01/static-methods-and-classes-are-always.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this usage of a static class is fine - especially in a single-threaded application.  Like others have said, your only alternative is to pass around some sort of contextual object that contains these lists.

My personal opinion, in this instance, is that you have chosen the best solution for your problem.  It is easy to implement, easy to use, and easy to change if need be down the road.