# Cons of static utility classes in java?

Tags: java, static

What are the cons of creating static utility classes? The more I've made, the more I find them extremely useful. I understand that they lack object oriented design, but I still love them probably more than I should. Are there any other cons for their use?

Comment: Though this is related to Java, you can check out a similar question about C# in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333690/static-classes-in-c-whats-the-pros-cons

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with them, in the right context.  If you have free-standing, stateless methods (such as those found in `java.lang.Math`), then a static class is the perfect place for them.  The only reason they're in a class at all is because Java has no concept of free-standing methods.

Comment: I see, that is a fair point. What if I added in object storage to the static class, making it more a static singleton?

Comment: @Aedon: As soon as it becomes stateful, then unit-testing becomes difficult.  I would restrict my advice to "pure" methods.

Answer (score 13):

The main disadvantage IMO is the impossibility, using most of the mocking frameworks, to mock the implementation of such utility methods in order to unit-test some class using these utility methods.

For example, Using `System.currentTimeMillis()` is easy to get the current time. But when you have to test a class which uses the current time to do some work, it's impossible to mock the method to make it return a specific point in time. Using an object implementing a `Clock` interface and injected into the object to test make it much easier: you can create a mock Clock implementation returning a specific date when asked to get the current time.

Comment: Can you explain this statement? What makes them difficult to unit test?

Comment: That is true for the `currentTimeMillis()` method. But like @Oli Charlesworth said, the `Math` api is going to be pretty set in stone.

Comment: Yes, but the same applies. Suppose you have a corner-case in the middle of a method if the cosinus of some computed value is equal to 0.5. It's much easier to mock a MathEngine object and make it return 0.5 to test the corner-case than to find a set of input values that will make, after all the previous computations, the Math.cos method return 0.5. Especially if the previous computation depends on the current time :-)

Comment: @JB: That sounds pretty contrived!  What would happen if the object-under-test relies on the result of the call to `cos` corresponding to the input it actually generated?

Comment: If the object under test knew that the result of cos would be 0.5, it would have no reason to call Math.cos. When it calls Math.cos, it expects getting a valid cosinus value, but this value might be anything. Anyway, the point of a test is not to make a method do impossible things. Its point is to test a method and to cover every possible path.

Comment: @JB: I don't mean that the object "knows" the result.  I'm thinking of a situation where you might be taking advantage of some trigonometric identity (e.g. [the cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_rule)), where injecting "arbitrary" values for the result of `cos` would result in impossible geometric results.

Comment: This might be a possibibility, but it might not. Being able to mock the cos method can be useful. The fact that it's not so useful in a particular case doesn't mean it isn't in other. It's the responsibility of the test to make what's needed and useful to test the method. Mocking is just a tool, but a very useful one.

Comment: @JB: I understand your point.  But personally, I'm very uneasy about tests that are heavily tied to the precise implementation of the object-under-test (that know to inject a "fake" value on the 5th call to `cos`, for instance).

Comment: Static data, bad. Static methods, meh.

Comment: @ tom hawtin care to explain?

Comment: You can inject a utility class in exactly the same way, right? What am I missing? It seems you just have the stub implement a static method, inject it using a setter or other method, then call that injected variable in the same way you call any other injected variable, except as a static method instead of creating an object first. For example `MyClass m = new MyClass(); m.setClock(new myFakeClock());` then inside of `m` call `this.clock.currentTimeMillis()` where `this.clock` is either the fake or real utility class.

Comment: @Max the question is about static utility methods. You can't inject a fake System class, with a stubbed currentTimeMillis() method. Because DI is about injecting objects, not classes, and about mocking instance methods of injected obects.

Answer (score 4):

I had talked about this sometime ago in a post which you can find [here](http://itmusings.com/design/the-evil-static-method).

The chief problems in the usage of a static method are:

1. Mockability as the other posters pointed out.
2. Several versions of a static class can be loaded in an application depending on the class loader hierarchy and class path configured for the entire hierarchy of class loaders. (A third element is also if the class loader is configured as parent first or child first) Makes testing and debugging this a nightmare.
3. A static method cannot be inherited from. Hence violates [OCP (Open Closed Principle)](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf) i.e. a static method is not extensible. Look at Log4J for typical problems with static methods.
4. A static method is not amenable for the application of either the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf) or the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. It is not possible to have alternate implementations of a similar algorithm depending on individual use cases without recourse to copious amounts of hand written code sprayed liberally with "if conditions".

But if the method itself is not too cumbersome and is pretty much predictable (i.e. not too many requirements for different variations of the implementations etc.) then there is no reason why a static method would not fit the bill. So, moral of the story is Use it but be aware of side affects.