# Global functions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Kind of embarassing to ask this question as it feels like it should be obvious but after god only knows how many google searches I cant seem to find what I'm looking for. Perhaps im just searching the wrong words?

anyway I've started working on a basic to get to grips with the WP8 device to start porting some of my old c# games to play on my shiny new lumia. 
anyways. I've created a simple app with a few pages that dont really do a whole lot. few buttons/images etc. the buttons do things and all thats fine and dandy. now i'm wanting to use a particular function on multiple pages but cant for the life of me find where I can put a function in 1 single place that I can use from everywhere.

ie

```
public void(string blah) {
    MessageBox.Show("This is button " + blah);
}
```

I'd rather not have to have a copy of the same functions on all my created pages. I've got my class file and that works all nice and dandy. Ideally i'd like a functions file. Even if I have to declare it with a line I'd be happy. beats having hundreds of line of the same code throughout my app.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword is `static`

```
public static void  print(string blah) {
    MessageBox.Show("This is button " + blah);
}
```

lets say this function is in class x 
then you would call it as followed: `x.print("blah");`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [WP8 how to create base-page & use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398590/wp8-how-to-create-base-page-use-it) to create base pages with methods, or like what @Svexo said, you can create static functions but also bear in mind [Static classes in C#, what's the pros/cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333690/static-classes-in-c-whats-the-pros-cons) that recklessly creating static functions all over the place is going create problems in the long run

Comment: had an interesting read though those posts about the static classes. specially that guy who didn't get a job because he used them!
I'll look more into this non visual inheriting method and post back with my results :P